# Storm topology deployment using maven

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a pipeline for stream processing as follow.

First, I queue messages using Kafka.
Next, I apply some business logic by creating a Storm topology.
Finally, I push the stream of data into Elastic Search.

All of this is bundled into a Maven project. After I build the Maven project, I have to manually deploy my topology to the Storm repository. Is there a way to automate this process? Meaning, can I create/build my Maven project in such a way that as soon as it builds the JAR, it uploads the JAR along with the name of the Topology defining class on to the Storm repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, what you mean by "uploading to Storm repo", however, I guess that `exec-maven-plugin` is your friend: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

You can trigger the execution of arbitrary programs during the build. Thus, you can provide a shell script that does the upload and just call it after the jar is assembled.